# alias program='python3 $(which program)' works in bash, breaks in zsh

Tags: zsh, alias

I'm running a custom version of ansible for each code base and need to run it with python3. (On MacOS)

For this purpose I run

```
    source env.rc
```

in every codebase before I run ansible-playbook. It contains:

```
    #!/bin/sh

    source ~/src/ansible/hacking/env-setup &> /dev/null
    alias ansible-playbook='python3 $(which ansible-playbook)'
    alias ansible-vault='python3 $(which ansible-vault)'
```

This has worked fine in bash, but since I switched to zsh as recommened by MacOS it fails with sort of a self-referencing loop:

```
    ansible git:(master) ✗ ansible-playbook webserver.yml -u root --tags rebuildcard
    '/usr/local/bin/python3: can't open file '/Users/jd/projects/meezy/ansible/ansible-playbook:': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What is the best way to set this alias? Or if not, why was it working in bash, but not in zsh

Comment: Using similar alias on my side works. Isn't the error message clear? Maybe you can just try to run `/usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/jd/projects/meezy/ansible/ansible-playbook webserver.yml -u root --tags rebuildcard`

Comment: There is no ansible-playbook in that folder its in ~/src/ansible/somesubfolder where github:/ansible keeps its script. Its supposed to expose ansible-playbook whereever it got placed from after running source ~/src/ansible/hacking/env-setup &> /dev/null

Comment: I wouldn't use an alias at all. Create a virtual environment and install Ansible in that environment. Then you can simply run `ansible-playbook` and `ansible-vault`, and they will automatically use the correct version of `python`.

Answer (score 0):

As @chepner pointed out - you would be better served by using https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#homebrew-in-macos to manage your python versions, usually with `.python-version` files checked in to git.

If you don't want to explore that, sharing `~/src/ansible/hacking/env-setup` may lead to more concise help.

Comment: I want to understand why I should use pyenv, as I am not intending to switch python versions

Comment: env-setup is here https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.12.1/hacking/env-setup